# How to update multiple fields using query builder in Doctrine2?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder

I have to update multiple fields, when I tried to update fields in other table using foreign key id using `getRepository()` and `findOneById()` getting bug as unrecognised field, so then later tried to implemented it using query builder. but query doesn't get executing getting bug like undefined fields.

This is the code I have tried:

```php
$this->em
    ->getRepository('Application_Entity_Company', 'c')
    ->findOneBy(array('c.userId'=>$post['user_id']));
```

and

```php
$qb->update('Application_Entity_Company', 'c')
    ->set('c.name', $post['name'])
    ->set('c.mobile', $post['mobile'])
    ->set('c.email', $post['email'])
    ->where($qb->expr()
    ->eq('c.userId', ':id'))
    ->setParameter('id', $post['user_id'])
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

Here `userId` is the foreign key. I have to update the fields of user details in user entity using the `userId`.

Comment: You are updating company entity, you have to update user entity. I guess you should use like : $qb->update('Application_Entity_User', 'u')->set('u.name', $post['name'])->set('u.mobile', $post['mobile'])->set('u.email', $post['email'])->where('u.userId', ':id'))->setParameter('id', $post['user_id'])->getQuery()->execute();

Comment: I have to update in company entity, updated fields are there in company but I have to update based on userId. It is in user entity.

Comment: Can you please post your error message? I think c.userId may wrong here your relation field name which is given in entity will come. I have post previous comment based on this sentence : " I have to update the fields of user details in user entity using the userId."

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have solved the problem. :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with not obvious usage of `set` method. Second parameter is expected to be an expression instead of the obvious user input.

For sample incorrectly used `set` code:

```
$queryBuilder = $entityManager->getRepository()->createQueryBuilder('u');
$queryBuilder->update()
    ->set('u.userFirstName', 'Michael')
    ->where('u.userId = :userId')
    ->setParameter('userId', 111)
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

SQL representation:

```
UPDATE user SET user_first_name = Michael WHERE user_id = 111;
```

You will get following error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 49 near 'Michael WHERE': Error:
>   'Michael' is not defined.

This is because your database assumes `Michael` is a table column name which for obvious reasons is not defined.

Solution is to either use `\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr` or by binding parameters:

```
$queryBuilder = $mapper->getRepository()->createQueryBuilder('u');
$queryBuilder->update()
    ->set('u.userFirstName', ':userFirstName')// Alternatively $queryBuilder->expr()->literal('Michael')
    ->where('u.userId = :userId')
    ->setParameter('userId', 111)
    ->setParameter('userFirstName', 'Michael')
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```